# CSS Style not hidden image correctly on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a site trying to find out how [this page](http://foodpress.us/store/home) can do something like this:
[image]

I looked at the .css and HTML from their page to know how the can build something like that.

Well... this is my result:

[image]

The problem is when I try to display the site in a mobile phone, I can't hidden my image, also if I make "hidden-xs" in the div of my image the text is not centered.

On the left side you can se what I want to do And on the right side my result:
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="white_bg">
    <div id="mobile-app-sections" class="container">
        <div class="container-medium">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5 into-row border app-image-wrap">
                    <img class="app-phone" src="img/device.jpg">
                </div> <!--col-->
                <div class="col-xs-7 into-row border">
                    <h2>foodpress in your mobile! </h2>
                    <h3 class="green-text">Get our app, it's the fastest way to order food on the go.</h3>

                    <div class="row border" id="getapp-wrap">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 border">
                            <a href="http://" target="_blank">
                                <img class="get-app" src="img/get-app-store.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 border">
                            <a href="http://" target="_blank">
                                <img class="get-app" src="img/get-google-play.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--row-->
                </div> <!--col-->
            </div> <!--row-->
        </div> <!--container-medium-->

        <div class="mytable border" id="getapp-wrap2">
            <div class="mycol border">
                <a href="http://" target="_blank">
                    <img class="get-app" src="img/get-app-store.png">
                </a>
            </div> <!--col-->
            <div class="mycol border">
                <a href="http://" target="_blank">
                    <img class="get-app" src="img/get-google-play.png">
                </a>
            </div> <!--col-->
        </div> <!--mytable-->
    </div> <!--container-->
</div><!-- End white_bg -->
```

**CSS**

```
    /* CUSTOM CSS */

img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.border{
    border:0px solid red;
}


.mytable{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.mytable .mycol{
    display:table-cell;
}

#mobile-app-sections{
    padding-top:30px;
}

.container-medium {
    max-width:800px;
    margin:auto;
}

#mobile-app-sections h2{
    margin-top:22%;
}

#mobile-app-sections h3{
    margin:auto auto 25px;
}

#getapp-wrap2{
    margin:auto;
    width:300px;
}

#getapp-wrap2 img{
    max-width:130px;
}

#getapp-wrap2 .mycol{
    width:150px;
}

#getapp-wrap2{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML and CSS I took from [this site](http://foodpress.us/store/home) trying to find out how can I resolve my problem.

**What Am I doing wrong?**

Also the image that I want to hidden have this class: class="app-phone" that I couldn't find in the page (May be here is the problem?).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I believe you need to add a media query for the mobile resolutions of interest, and in it, define your phone image css with, in part,  display:none.

Answer (score 0):

The text isn't centered when you hide the image because it's still limited to 7 out of the 12 total columns. You need to use the full 12 cols on mobile and then limit to 7 at the next standard breakpoint size (small).

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-5 into-row border app-image-wrap">
    <img class="app-phone" src="img/device.jpg">
</div> <!--col-->

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 into-row border">
```

Further reading: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Is not just center the text, also the margin below the ios and android button. However the site not use this solution

Comment: Use margin bottom on `#getapp-wrap2` or the images contained within. Then apply a media query to remove at larger sizes if you find it pushes out the vertical positioning

Answer (score 0):

xs is used for screen sizes below 576px, sm is above 576px. So you should change your xs's to sm. So when you write a `col-xs-6` it tells the browsers to make that column 50% width under 576px (in mobile) if you want it to be 50% for tablets and desktops and 100% for mobile you should use `col-sm-6`